# How to change a CACHE variable in cmake file run by -P mode

Tags: caching, cmake

I have a cache variable created with

```
set(firmware_version ${FirmwareVersion} CACHE STRING "firmware")
```

and passed this variable to a cmake file with

```
COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -Dfirmware_version:STRING=${firmware_version} -P "C:/Projekt/Lapp/PDM/Versioning.cmake"
```

Now I am changing this variable in `Versioning.cmake` with a variable

```
set(firmware_version ${FirmwareVersion} CACHE STRING "firmware" FORCE)
```

But I cannot see the changes made to the variable visible to `CMakeLists.txt` file.

I am forcing the reconfigure of the cmake with

```
add_custom_target(versioning ALL
DEPENDS version_tag
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT version_tag
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -Dfirmware_version:STRING=${firmware_version} -P "C:/Projekt/Lapp/PDM/Versioning.cmake"
    )
```

Comment: CMake variables are accessible only during the **configuration** stage, because only this stage is processed by CMake. **Build** stage is controlled by make,nmake or other **build utility**. That is, you cannot change CMake variables when you project is built. The only way for change CMake variables is to re-configure the project.

Comment: You mentioned "Now I am changing this variable in Versioning.cmake with a variable".  The type of `add_custom_command()` being used will only run during pre build, this means if the target is not out of date the command won't run again.  You may want to use a custom command that `DEPENDS` on `Versioning.cmake`.

Comment: Putting an absolute path like `C:/Projekt/Lapp/PDM/Versioning.cmake` is a terrible idea. You should instead make it relative to the current source directory like `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/PDM/Versioning.cmake` (or whatever the actual path is).